# "Collaboration skills" refers [3rd pes sing] to skills that... OR "Collaboration skills" refer [plural] to skills that...?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

When we are talking about words or phrases that are plural in form, but that are in themselves singular, which verb form do we use?

Example:

> *Collaboration skills* refers to skills that...

Here I've used the 3rd person singular verb form, since *Collaboration skills* is one single phrase (just as I would use the singular verb form in *The phrase* collaboration skills *refers to skills that...*)

On the other hand, the form of the phrase is obviously plural, so perhaps the plural verb form should be used instead?

Comment: One phrase: singular.

Comment: You can view "collaboration skills" as a singular unit or plural skills.

Comment: If you're worried by the ambiguity, you could say "The phrase 'collaboration skills' refers to skills that..." or "Collaboration skills are skills that..."

Comment: Thank you all! :) @StuartF – good sollutions!